# При обращении обращении к функции on_press=self.btn_press весь код крашится

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyrogram

При обращении к функции `on_press=self.btn_press` весь код крашится, если эту строку убрать то код будет работать нормально, но эта строка обращается к функции которая отвечает за нажатие кнопки, помогите пожалуйста `строка 46`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window


from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait

from pyrogram.types import ChatPermissions

Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)    # установка цвета нового фона
#Config.set("graphics", "relizeble", "0")# ---\
#Config.set("graphics", "width", "400")   #    \ высота и ширина экрана, изменять его потом нельзя
#Config.set("graphics", "heigth", "600")#------/

api_hash = "" # переменная для будующих данных
api_id = "" # переменная для будующих данных
class MyApp(App):
        def build(self):

            fl = AnchorLayout() # этот лаяут будет делать ПО динамическим

            bl = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", size_hint = (.5, .5))# тоже лаяут но создает боксы

            self.test = TextInput(text = "api_id", font_size=25, background_color=[9, 9, 9, 9])# Этот лаяут как input для получения данных от пользователя
            self.text_input1 = TextInput(text = "api_hash", font_size=25, background_color=[9, 9, 9, 9])# Этот лаяут как input для получения данных от пользователя

            bl.add_widget(self.test)  # создаю Text_input через BoxLayout
            bl.add_widget(self.text_input1)# создаю Text_input через BoxLayout


            bl.add_widget(Button(       # создаю кнопkу через BoxLayout
                text = "подтвердить",
                font_size=25,  # font_size рaзмер шрифта




                on_press=self.btn_press,  # on_press нажата, эта строка подводит весь код 






                background_color=[1, 1, 1, 1]  # background_color цвет RGBA в %
                #background_normal="", # background_normal  делает цвет ярче
            ))



            fl.add_widget(bl) # отношу BoxLayout к fl
            #s = Scatter()
            #s.add_widget(fl)
            return fl # возращаю fl


        def btn_press(self):
            global api_id           #глобальная переменная
            global api_hash             #глобальная переменная
            print(self.text_input.text)         #вывожу данные из Text_input
            print(self.text_input1.text)#

            api_id= self.text_input.text1#

            api_hash=self.text_input1.text1#

app = Client("00ef8b3beaab981d8661a5e596123447", api_id = api_id, api_hash= api_hash)#
@app.on_message(filters.text & filters.private)#
def echo(client, message):#
    message.reply_text(message.text)#


if __name__ == "__main__":#
    MyApp().run()#

    #app.run()#
```

Ошибка:

> TypeError: btn_press() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: а если написать on_press=self.press не поможет ?

Comment: on_press это идет от библиотеки kivy а self.btn_press это обращение к функции btn_press(ну или как это называется, я про self) а как вы предлагаете поменять на self.press то я просто буду "обращаться" к несуществующей функции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Буквальный перевод ошибки: `btn_press()` принимает 1 позиционный аргумент, но было передано 2 (аргумента).

Чтобы устранить ошибку, просто добавьте еще один параметр методу `btn_press()`, пример:

```
def btn_press(self, arg):
    ...
```

Если смотреть в [справке](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html), функция-обработчик нажатия должна принимать параметр `instance`. Т.к. у вас это не просто функция, а метод, то первым параметром в него придет `self` (объект `MyApp`, от которого вызван метод), а уже вторым - `instance`.

Comment: спасибо помогло теперь другая ошибка))))))))00

Comment: @user421810 если ответ помог, вы можете отметить его как принятый (поставить галку слева от ответа).